# Getting a URL of some picture from Google search

Tags: python

New to Python. I'm trying to find a way to get a url of the first picture I get from google search for some string. For example if I type "dog" I would like to get the first picture url for dog. I don't care which one just some url from Google image search.

Is it possible? what is the easiest way to do it? I saw from previous threads many ways to extract/download the image - but I just need the url and it doesn't matter which one.

Comment: Are you using `requests` or `selenium` to try this out? It's best to start with the code you've tried and go from there.

Comment: I'm using requests

Answer (score 1):

This should work, simply replace the word to get images of anything.
Make sure you have requests and BeautifulSoup, if not run this command:

> pip install requests beautifulsoup4

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

word = 'dog'
url = 'https://www.google.com/search?q={0}&tbm=isch'.format(word)
content = requests.get(url).content
soup = BeautifulSoup(content,'lxml')
images = soup.findAll('img')

for image in images:
    print(image.get('src'))
```

Comment: Thank you! Although it does not prints a url.  It prints something like: `images/dog.png`

Comment: Not sure why it's not working for you, I am getting this output: https://i.imgur.com/DiZP31R.png

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about Google, but I do know an easy way to do this with Bing. There's a PyPI module called `bing-image-urls` (https://pypi.org/project/bing-image-urls) , and this will do the job nicely. It's pretty easy to use. Just install it with:

```
pip install bing-image-urls
```

Then, in your python script, have this code:

```
from bing_image_urls import bing_image_urls

url = bing_image_urls("dog", limit=1)[0]
print(url)
```

Just replace "dog" in this example with whatever you want.

Hopefully this answers your question
Thanks!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).